# Python input function, printing

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple function where python would calculate age depending on your year input. I've tried several ways and I haven't had luck atm.

ps. sorry, I'm a newbie at this.

```
ame = input(" Enter your name: ")

age = input(" When were you born?: ")

print("Hello " + name + "! You are " + input (2021 - age)
```

Comment: ```print("Hello " + name + "! You are ",2021- int(age))```

Comment: Another overly literal use of [python-requests] tag, please read the tag description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do: convert `age` to `integer`, then subtract it from 2021.

```
ame = input(" Enter your name: ")
age = input(" When were you born (year) ?: ")
print("Hello " + name + "! You are ",2021- int(age))
```

Comment: f-strings are more readable. Consider using `print(f"Hello {name}! You are {2021-int(age)}")`

Comment: @not_speshal, thank you for your suggestion. I am aware of that. Actually, ```f-strings``` are a little advanced. So I deterred from using it

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

# get the year so it works all the time.
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
name = input(" Enter your name: ")
birth_year = input(" When were you born (year) ?: ")

# calclute the age
age = year - int(birth_year)

print("Hello " + name + "! You are ", age)
```

There are other ways to print which might look more clean:

```
print(f'Hello {name}! You are {age}')
```

or

```
print("Hello {0}! You are {1}".format(name, age))
```

***To make it a function:***

```
import datetime

def age_cal(birth_year):
    # get the year so it works all the time.
    year = datetime.datetime.today().year
    return year - int(birth_year)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = input(" Enter your name: ")
    birth_year = input(" When were you born (year) ?: ")
    age = age_cal(birth_year)

    print("Hello {0}! You are {1}".format(name, age))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s go through the code sample you provided line-by-line.

```py
name = input(" Enter your name: ")
```

This line creates a variable called name and assigns it to the return value of the built-in function `input`.

```py
age = input(" When were you born? ")
```

This does the same, but for the variable age. Note that this stores a string (some characters) not an int. You’ll probably want to convert it, like this:

```py
age = int(age)
```

Next, you’re trying to print:

```py
print("Hello " + name + "! You are " + input (2021 - age)
```

But to figure out what to print, Python has to evaluate the return of `input(2021-age)`. (Remember in your code that `age` was a string; you can’t subtract strings and ints).

You’ve got another problem here- you’re prompting and waiting for input again, but you don’t need to. You’ve already stored the user’s input in the `age` and `name` variables.

So what you really want to do is:

```py
print("Hello, " + name + "! You are " + 2021 - age )
```

Now, if you wanted to be a little more concise, you could also do:

```py
print(f"Hello, {name}! You are {2021 - age}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert input to `int` and `format` your print statement, like below.

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = int(input("When were you born? (year): "))  # convert input to int
print("Hello {}! You are {} years old".format(name, (2021-age)))  # format output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple function with `datatime` like this:

```
from datetime import date

name = input(" Enter your name: ")
year = int(input(" When were you born?: "))

def calculateAge(year):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - year
    return age

print("Hello " + name + "! You are " + str(calculateAge(year)))
```

Answer (score -3):

This isn't  a function for that you have to use def anyway this is the code
Code-

```
from datetime import date
todays_date = date.today()
name = input(" Enter your name: ")
dob = int(input(" When were you born?: "))
print("Hello " + name + "! You are " + todays_date.year - dob)
```

Comment: Please test your answers before posting. What is `num(2021)`?